# Bootstrap image grid is not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I created an image grid using bootstrap 4. 2 bigger landscape photos up, 3 smaller portrait photos down.Perfectly aligned.But whenever I reduce the width of the page, they go crazy.The 2 big ones are going one into the other, then down, then the portrait ones are good, but the 1st is to the left, the 2nd to the right, the 3rd more to the right like stairs.

I tried using col-sm-6 classes and stuff like that.

```
<div class = "showcase">
                        <!-- First row with 2 landscape wallpapers -->
                        <div class = "presentl">
                        <div class = "row" id = "land">
                          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <img src="img/land1.jpg" class="rounded float-left" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350">
                          </div>
                          <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <img src="img/land2.jpg" class="rounded float-right" alt = "Landscape wallpaper" width = "500" height = "350"> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <!-- Second row with 3 portrait wallpapers-->
                        <div class = "row" id = "port">
                            <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">                  
                                <img src="img/p1.jpeg" class="rounded float-left" id = "firstp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">
                            </div>
                            <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" id = "fix">                  
                                <img src="img/p2.jpg" id = "secondp" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350"> 
                            </div>

                            <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                 <img src="img/p3.jpg" class = "rounded float-right" alt = "Portrait wallpaper" width = "200" height = "350">
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

For extra large,large and medium devices they should be just like I said.2 up,3 down, and for smaller and extra smaller devices on/row(one on the top of the other, spaced a bit).

Comment: Can you show us your relevant custom css?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class="img-fluid" to your images as mentioned here on documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Comment: How can I use both image rounded-left and rounded-right with the img-fluid class?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth it to structure it more like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="#"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Your first line of code will set the width on various devices, but then your image holder will set how big your image is inside the bootstrap square. For that you can use em or % units to size your image (so width may be 95%, for example) in your css.

Your image size will be controlled by css using:

```
 .img-holder > img { 
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%
  }
```

Also, don't forget to use the meta tag:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, none of those worked.What I did was to replace the showcase class with container-fluid.Very easy.